# How/where to change the default size of inline images?

Tags: media

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out **how/where to change the default size of inline images** (that is, images that have been inserted into the body by way of the wysiwyg editor's `Insert/Edit Image` button). It's likely that I'm missing something obvious here as I've only had one cup of coffee today... tragic, I know.

Comment: Wow... I really thought this would be such an easy question to answer! Is there anything in my description that I can clarify?

Comment: Most importantly, which WYSIWYG editor have you installed and enabled?  I didn't think D7 Core had a WYSIWYG included by default.

Comment: In my experience there's no such thing as a default size for images added using the WYSIWYG...the full sized image is always inserted into the body. If you're using IMCE then that's a whole different question. It would be wise to update your question with all the information you can about your current setup.

Comment: 1) What WYSIWYG editor in particular you are using? An accurate answer to your question might rely on this important detail. I might actually have a good answer, but then, I don't know your exact editor. 2) What version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [Image Resize Filter](http://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) or [Image Autosize Filter](http://drupal.org/project/image_autosize) modules. These module add a filter to your input format that automatically resizes images added through the WYSIWYG editor. Image Autosize Filter allows you to set a maximum width, which seems like it would work for your case.

As a precautionary measure, you could add some CSS like this as well:

```
.node img {
    max-width: 450px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border:0px;
    margin:0em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS, you could do something like:

```
.class-of-whatever-div-your-content-is-in img {
   width: 228px;
   height: 228px;
}
```

and then all images in there would be 228 x 228 squares.  You could use max-width and/or max-height if you wanted to get fancy and not potentially upscale any small images, too.  (Add some !importants if necessary depending on what your WYSIWYG editor may put in, too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write custom JavaScript to adjust the width of images that have been inserted using WYSIWYG. Then you can use [JS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector) module to inject your little JavaScript on required paths.

One time, I had to make sure that width of images uploaded using CKEditor does not exceed the max width of my theme.

I used following code. You can do same for basically any node page by passing the correct ID to jQuery function.

```
//adjust the width of images shown using views
var views=$(".view-content");
$(views).each(function(){
var max_width=$(this).width();
$(this).find('img').attr('style','max-width:'+max_width+'px;');

});

//adjust the width of images on node pages
max_content_width=$("#main .content").width();
$("#main .content").find('img').attr('style','max-width:'+max_content_width+'px;');
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others here, the default inline images button just inserts an image as-is, so the answer to your question is technically that there is no "default" size.

That's not very helpful though :P What you want is some way to get the image to be processed by imagecache/image (depending on whether you use D6 or D7) so you can apply a preset/style. Anything that allows the image to be rendered with core's theme() function will do the trick.

Taking pre-existing rendered markup and retroactively applying image styles would be another approach, you could use querypath or something similar but something tells me that you'd end up killing kittens..

There's a WYSIWYG Fields module that is designed to give you the best of both worlds (the control from rendering fields + the ease of WYSIWYG editing) - http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_fields. That sounds like a good option for you to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), for example, you can always write your own CKEditor plugin. Although it sounds scary, it is actually more easy to do than what it sounds, and it is well documented [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials), [here](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-for-drupal), and [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Enterprise). Examples are included in the links. The cool thing about writing your own plugins is that you have ultimate control of the WYIWYG editor's functionality because your plugin interacts both with Drupal/PHP (using custom CKEditor hooks) and the editors' JavaScript interface.

In your case you could write a custom settings page in Drupal through which you specify the default image size, or as suggested elsewhere, interface with the image cache API (which is pretty elegant, btw). Then you could copy/take ideas from whatever JavaScript code currently inserts the images, and modify it to your will.

Once you implement your own plugin, the sky is the limit. Good luck!